# How to create a tiny button?

Tags: asp.net, button

I have a need to create a tiny button but I cannot do that with its width. 
It seems that button's width has a minimum value. When I set its height is 5px and width is 5px, it's OK in Visual Studio but when it's rendered in Web browsers, only its height is right.

Do you know how to set button's width to a small very?

Comment: Please be more specific. What browser are you using. Did you try other browsers can you give some code how you create your button and maybe any additional CSS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the padding to 0.

```
padding: 0px;
```

Browsers by default add padding. It also varies from browser to browser.